# How to execute two jquery animate function in parallel

Tags: jquery, parallel-processing, jquery-animate

i know that we can two jquery animate function in parallel like this way

```
$(function () {
    $("#first").animate({
       width: '200px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#second").animate({
       width: '600px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
});
```

but my situation is bit different.
i have one button and one div whose opacity is set to zero. so div is invisible. i want when a user will click a button then a div will be create dynamically and placed at center. center div size will increase gradually.

so when dynamic div will be placed at center then i need to append my invisible div inside the dynamic div. now i want to increase dynamic div size with animate function and as well as i want to set opacity 1 to invisible child div. so i want these two animation should run parallel.

because when dynamic div resizing will be completed then child div's opacity will also reach at 1. guide me with a small sample how to achieve it.

here is my js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3jrt48s4/

which anyone can see and understand how i want to animate two div in parallel and those two div's name as follows "UPSContainer", "UPS_rate_time" thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you append the invisible-div to the dynamic-div in the callback-function of the dynamic-div animation. That way the invisible becomes visible only when the animation is finished. Just pull the  invisible-div out of the callback and insert it in the main function so both will run simultaneously.

```
function toggleUPSOverlay(e) {
    if (!data.isAnimating) {
        if ($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')) {
            data.isAnimating = true;
            $els.UPSContainer.show();
            // these actions are pulled off the complete-callback and inserted here
            // they are reversed and .appendTo is used so it looks a bit smoother
            $('.UPS_rate_time').fadeIn(800)).appendTo($els.UPSContainer);
            // now the fadeIn and the animate runs simultaneously
            $els.UPSContainer.animate({/* ... */}, {
                duration: 800,
                /* ... */
                complete: function() {
                    data.isAnimating = false; // the only thing left here
                }
            });
        } else {/* ... */}
    }
}
```

I hope [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jrt48s4/28/) shows what you want.

Comment: i want to do the both at same time like one div will resize and move and child div will change gradually its opacity from 0 to 1. is it possible?

Comment: You may set `fadeIn(800)` to get same runtimes. More *same time* than this isn't possible. Both animations (fade and resize) start at (nearly) same time, and with same duration end at (nearly) same moment.

Comment: did u update your js fiddle? i voted you for your effort. thanks